# Echo command not displaying

Tags: shell, shell-script

I have a shell script with the following:

```
STATUS=`/home/scripts/200check.sh $RUOK_URL`
```

Inside of 200check.sh I have some `echo` commands, but these commands are not displayed in the terminal. I guess they're consumed by something else?

Does anyone know how I can have the `echo` commands displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*echo* outputs messages to stdout, and they are captured by the very same **`` ` ` ``** operator.

It's standard practice to send warnings or error messages to stderr instead. In bash, you would use:

```
echo "warning: blah" >&2
```

stderr is normally not affected by pipes or command substitution operators (although it can still be redirected).

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much. I'm pretty new to Shell Scripting, thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

The output from the script is saved in the `$STATUS` variable because you invoke it using back-ticks (a nicer way of doing it would be to use `$(...)`, which nests easier). Try displaying the value of `$STATUS` to see if your expected output is there.